# Logs not forwarded (but fluentd container running)

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I have a fluentd container that after a week of working regularly, it stops forwarding logs to elasticsearch.

If a 'docker logs' that container it shows me all logs, but after a certain date/time these are not forwarded.

Fluentd config is this:

```
</source>
 @type      forward
 @label     @mainstream
 bind       0.0.0.0
 port       24224
</source>

<label @mainstream>
 <match **>
   @type copy    <store>
     @type               elasticsearch
     host                elasticsearch
     port                9200
     logstash_format     true
     logstash_prefix     fluentd
     logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
     include_tag_key     true
     type_name           access_log
     tag_key             @log_name
     <buffer>
       flush_mode        interval
       flush_interval    1s
     </buffer>    
   </store>  </match>
</label>
```

Do you have any suggestions to find the root of this problem?
Thank you in advance.